# Flutter signature 5.0.1 signature can extand outside the bounds of the widget

Tags: flutter

I am using this
Signature 5.0.1 package for flutter
https://pub.dev/packages/signature

To handle the signatures and I am trying to keep them inside a certain container, the signature itself has a defined width and height property but it doesn't contain the signature itself when you start drawing it, once the draw has started you can simply expand it down and left as much as you want, thank you for all of your answers.
[presentation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4cp3.png)
[code for the signature](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UO0Sy.png)

[extended presentation of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cC56h.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your `Signature` widget with `ClipRRect`.

```
ClipRRect(
  child: Signature(
    height: 200, // Or any other height you would like your widget to be
    controller: _signatureController,
    backgroundColor: pogoGreyBgColor,
  ),
);
```

That will keep all of the drawings within this widget's bounds.

Answer (score 1):

Use SizedBox() as parent of Signature(), and ClipRRect() as parent of SizedBox(),

This solves my problem.

```
                   ClipRRect(
                      child: SizedBox(
                          height: 280,
                          child: Signature(
                            controller: _controller,
                            height: 280,
                            backgroundColor: getNormalTextColor,
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
```

Comment: ClipRRect fixed it, thanks :)